# Find amount of numbers that are greater than x in text file

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I'm supposed to find the amount of "cars" in a data file that uses less than 22 OR 27 MPG in a city or highway. I'm supposed to write a program that calculates the number/amount of cars that have less than that mileage.

This is my code:

```
def GasGuzzlers(list1, list2):
  amount1 = 0
  amount2 = 0
  with open(list1, "r") as list1:
      line = list1.readline()
      for line in list1:
          while float(line) < 22.0:
              amount1+=1

  with open(list2, "r") as list2:
      line2 = list2.readline()
      for amount2 in list2:
          while float(line2) < 27.0:
              amount2+=1
  print(amount1, amount2)
```

It does not print anything out and I've tried multiple alternatives and get "0 0" as an output when I did. I feel like it shouldn't be this hard to find the number of cars who have less than a certain mileage.

This is my teacher's instruction if that helps:

> "Write a function countGasGuzzlers(list1, list2) that calculates the number of gas guzzlers among the vehicle models tested – for this program, define a “gas guzzler” as a car that gets EITHER less than 22 mpg city OR less than 27 mpg highway."

Comment: Indentation is wrong here. And change while to if

Comment: This loop won't terminate if the condition is true: `while float(line) < 22.0: amount1+=1`

Comment: @VenkataGogu: The indentation isn't "wrong", it just isn't the standard 4 spaces **recommended** in [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @martineau Actually, I fixed the indentation .. and I was being lazy as the editor has no "indent" key :)

Comment: @martineau When I posted my comment there isn't any space. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50686608/revisions

Comment: There's also a major problem with the second for loop: `for amount2 ...` vs `while float(line2)`, even if `while` was the correct control statement to use. Given the first readline seems to be to throw away a header line, I'd actually expect an exception to be thrown if it ever reached the second loop.

Comment: @VenkataGogu: Oh...sorry, didn't notice.

Comment: @quin what is the format of the two files? Problem also seems underspecified - how do you count a car which gets <22mpg city AND < 27mpg highway? Seems each line should contain two numbers, rather than two separate files. Were all cars test in both cases? does line 10 in each file represent the same car? Do you need to account for that? As a teacher, I'd expect you to ask these questions.

Comment: @kdopen Awesome! even I got same questions in mind. Adding to your questions, What does these list1 and list2 refers too?

Answer (score 0):

You are trapped in a endless while loop on:

```
while float(line) < 22.0:
while float(line2) < 27.0:
```

Change them to:

```
if float(line) < 22.0:
if float(line2) < 27.0:
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was such a minor error, I'll be sure to keep my eye out for it next time.